# Why after i add new mesh, the mesh's vertices doesn't show up in edit mode?

Tags: vertices

So in this case, i have created object and after that, i add new circle mesh. But the circle doesn't show its vertices while in edit mode like this [image]

You see, when i enter edit mode, the vertices doesn't show up,unlike when you usually go to edit mode, the vertices already show itself.

How to fix this? here is blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/2d2caac6fdea4427a51ce0758f50a34f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because Blender is in **Edge Select** mode. Change it to **Vertex Select** mode, and you will see the vertices

Comment: Oh okay t... thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Annoying me every time, then I try to extrude recently added circle

Comment: @EarvinWilliams don't forget to mark this post as the answer using the checkmark button below the votes arrows.

Comment: @Crantisz yeah i hate that too, especially when i try to make object using circle then forget to change the selection